# Unable to add web view dynamically...?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I want to add a web view dynamically into a linear layout.

I used the following code.

```
WebView web = new WebView(con);
            web.setId(1);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.loadUrl(Settings.liveAddUrl);
            layout.addView(web, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            break;
```

But, its opening browser instead of showing the content in the defined web view.

How to avoid this behavior and make it to show url contents in defined web view...?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: why do you say that is dynamically ?, I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only happen if the Url you are opening is making redirects.

You need to catch redirect attempts and load them in your own webview:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false; // prevents the default action - opening in system browser
    }
});
```

Comment: can I use queries instead ? like: `url?subpage=a&parameter1=p1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line before loading the URL as below

```
 web.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient() {

 });
```

Or

```
   web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: can you elaborate more ?